# Mysql - How to delete a record in which a space is located?

Tags: mysql

In the "title" field, I have the name eg: "X and y".

Regards
Igor

Comment: Please share table

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 delete from table where title like '% %'
```

but back-up the table beforehand in case you have records you don't want to delete

Answer (score 0):

Try this using like and % operations

```
    delete from [table name] where [Column name] like '%[text to find]%'
```

Example deleting a entry start with x and ends with y

```
    delete from [table_name] where [title] like 'x%y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Having to remove the phrase "Word1 Word2 Word3" the spacing between the words in the DELETE command I changed to "_" - it worked perfectly for me!

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE title LIKE 'Word1_Word2_Word3;
```